# Make gstreamer loop file names

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, http-live-streaming

I was able to successfully generate a hsl stream with gstreamer, with the following code:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v  \
               videotestsrc is-live=true \
               ! omxh264enc target-bitrate=2000000 control-rate=variable \
               ! "video/x-h264,profile=high,width=600,height=300" \
               ! mpegtsmux \
               ! hlssink \
               playlist-root=http://192.168.0.51:9000/hlssink/ \
               location=/home/attila/frontend/hlssink/hlssink.%05d.ts \
               max-files=5 \
               target-duration=10 \
               playlist-location=/home/attila/frontend/playlist.m3u8
```

It works very fine, but it has one flaw, the files genarated according to the property line of hlssink:

```
location=/home/attila/frontend/hlssink/hlssink.%05d.ts
```

are not looping. So the client should always reload the playlist. How can I make gstreamer to loop through an iteration of file names?

Comment: do you need playlist-root? in gst 1.6 I have playlist-location .. also I have `playlist-length` which when set on 0 means "infinite" (default is 5).. have you tried that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hlssink` needs `max-files=0` and `playlist-length=0` in order to keep all of your elementary stream .ts chunks and iterate (or loop) through all of your files.

- *max-files*: Maximum number of files to keep on disk. Once the maximum is reached,old files start to be deleted to make room for new
  ones. 0 keeps them all. Default 10.
- *playlist-length*: Length of HLS playlist. To allow players to conform to section 6.3.3 of the HLS specification, this should be at
  least 3. If set to 0, the playlist will be infinite. Default 5.

Complete reference of `hlssink` here: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-bad/html/gst-plugins-bad-plugins-hlssink.html